# Paypal payment failure - #10004 Invalid Transaction ID

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

I'm getting an error using PayPal payments Pro - but only at a certain quantity of a product. When ordering 55 items of a product the customer sees this error popup:

```
PayPal gateway has rejected request. The transaction id is not valid (#10004: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details).
```

I've checked the PayPal log and have found the response to be:

```
        [TIMESTAMP] => 2016-06-23T10:59:20Z
        [CORRELATIONID] => 241c536268ca3
        [ACK] => Failure
        [VERSION] => 72.0
        [BUILD] => 22386173
        [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10004
        [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
        [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The transaction id is not valid
        [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
        [AMT] => 107.25
        [CURRENCYCODE] => GBP
```

The strangest thing is that if the customer clicks "Place Order" a second time it will go through, or if the customer orders a different quantity (30 instead of 55 for example) the order still goes through.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? I don't know how it could just happen based on the quantity, and as far as I know PayPal responds with the transaction ID and it isn't something provided by Magento.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to copy the Abstract.php file from `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/` to `app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/`. You can make these changes directly to the core file if you really have to, but it's not recommended.

Find the `_exportLineItems` function (line 390 in my version 1.9) - this is what we're going to change.

Before the `foreach ($items as $item) {` (around line 412) add this:

```
$running_total = 0;
```

Before the `$request[sprintf($privateFormat, $i)] = $value;` (around line 423) add this:

```
if ($publicKey == 'amount') {
    $running_total += $value;
}
```

Before the `return $result;` (around line 427) add this:

```
// Check ITEMAMT. If different to running total, offset prices
if ((isset($request['ITEMAMT'])) && ($request['ITEMAMT'] > 0)) {
    if ($running_total <> (float) $request['ITEMAMT']) {
        $difference = ($running_total - (float) $request['ITEMAMT']);
        // Apply difference to first product.
        $request['L_AMT0'] = (string) ((float) $request['L_AMT0'] - $difference);
    }
}
```